# Task.detached crashing on init

Tags: asynchronous, swiftui, task

This empty app is crashing on load. I'm trying to execute a function on app load asynchronously, but it keeps crashing. I'm running [macOS v11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur) and Xcode 13 with Swift 5.5 and can't find what's wrong with it.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {

    init() {
        Controller.shared.load()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}

class Controller: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = Controller()

    @Published public var loaded = false
    @Published public var processing = false

    func load() {
        Task.detached {
            print("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

It compiles and runs but immediately crashes. There is no error message, it just crashes with

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

on `Controller.shared.load()`. If you comment out the Task.detached block it runs normally, but of course it doesn't start loading the object in the background which is what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: You should turn on “strict concurrency” this approach isn’t safe and apply the flags for race warnings. Older versions likely work because race warnings have been a work in progress with the new Concurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seemed to be somehow a bug related to the versions of Xcode 13.2.1 and macOS 11.7. If the project uses 11.7 as 'Deployment Target' I would get a crash, but if I change it to 11.6 it would work correctly. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, it is simply `.task` not `Task {}` and no need for any objects, e.g.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {

//    init() {
//        Controller.shared.load()
//    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
                .task {
                    print("Hello")
                    // or await a func declared outside the main actor context for a background thread
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//class Controller: ObservableObject {
//
//    static let shared = Controller()
//
//    @Published public var loaded = false
//    @Published public var processing = false

//    func load() {
//        Task.detached {
//            print("Hello")
//        }
//    }
//}
```

Comment: I'm working on Big Sur (macOS 11). The .task API is only available from macOS 12. The object is of course not necessary, but it is what I'm trying to init asynchronously on load. This pattern works on other apps I'm involved, but somehow if I start from scratch with a new empty project it crashes on Task.detached.

Comment: you almost never want `Task.detached`. You could reimplement .task yourself using `onAppear` and `onDisappear` and hold onto the task handle in a state. So I just googled it and found one you could try: https://github.com/shaps80/SwiftUIBackports/blob/main/Sources/SwiftUIBackports/Shared/Task/Task.swift